# Excel: SUMIFS with a variable number of conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I have data formatted similar to the table below. I want to to a sumifs on the 'Amount' column based on the values in the columns A, B, C and D.

| A | B | C | D | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 150 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 230 |
| 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 121 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 300 |

However, I want to create a formula where the number of conditioning variables (i.e. A, B, C, D) is a variable.

For example in the first row below, the sumifs would filter on [(A>1) and (B=0) and (C=2) and (D<0)].

In the second row the sumifs would filter on [(A=1) and (B=2)] and the third row will only filter on (A=1).

| A | B | C | D | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| >1 | 0 | 2 | <0 | ? |
| 1 | 2 | NA | NA | ? |
| 1 | NA | NA | NA | ? |

I think I can do this with a SUMPRODUCT but I'm not sure how to create an array of 1's for those variables that I do not want to filter on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want the results for the current samples to be 0, 0 and 121 respectively, try:

[image]

```
=MAP(G2:G4,H2:H4,I2:I4,J2:J4,LAMBDA(a,b,c,d,SUMIFS(E2:E5,A2:A5,IF(a="NA","<>",a),B2:B5,IF(b="NA","<>",b),C2:C5,IF(c="NA","<>",c),D2:D5,IF(d="NA","<>",d))))
```